# Get navigation/action bar height

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Xamarin Forms project which uses a custom toolbar for Android.
The toolbar is defined as Layout in axml and I set the minHeight for the Toolbar to the height of the standard action bar.

For a specific page in my app I have a custom page renderer where I need the height of the top (navigation/action) bar.

I've already tried to get the height with FindViewByID and get the height with TypedValue but that only gave me 0 back.

What else can I try to get the height of the bar in my page renderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**App.cs (Common code)**

```
public static int ActionBarHeight;
```

**MainActivity, in the OnCreate method (Droid part):**

```
Android.Content.Res.TypedArray styledAttributes = Theme.ObtainStyledAttributes(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.ActionBarSize });
App.ActionBarHeight = (int)(styledAttributes.GetDimension(0, 0) / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
styledAttributes.Recycle();
```

If you want the height in pixels:

```
App.ActionBarHeight = (int)styledAttributes.GetDimension(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Android, you can get the view's width and height only after `OnMeasure` method have been called. The `OnLayout` method will be called after `OnMeasure`. So you can get the width and height in `OnLayout` method.

```
class MyRender: PageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("OnLayout start");
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        for (int i = 0; i < ChildCount; i++)
        {
            Android.Views.View view = GetChildAt(i);
            int height = view.Height;
            int width = view.Width;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("height=" + height );
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("width=" + width );
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("OnLayout end");

    }

}
```

You must make sure that `OnMeasure` has been called before you get width and height ,or you will always get 0.